# javafx resizable pane and a rectangle inside

Tags: java, javafx, pane

I have a javafx pane and a rectangle inside it.. I want to make the rectangle fill all space of the pane without set the width or height manually, because the pane be resizable..

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the height and width properties of the Rectangle to the height and width properties of the Pane.

Or you might want to just set the background of the Pane using css and get rid of the Rectangle altogether.